# Modify alert() title (Javascript in Android Webview)

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Screenshot: [The page at file://](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vTGJ.jpg)

Is there anyway to modify the alert box title? Any help will be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: No, you can't control that. The browser does it as a security measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pointy says this is not possible due to the browser's security measure.

Comment: This is not the case, there are workarounds to achieve it. See other answers.

Answer (score 14):

Indeed you can envelop it using the following code:

```
    final Context myApp=this;

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, final android.webkit.JsResult result)
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(myApp)
        .setTitle("Simmon says...")
        .setMessage(message)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                new AlertDialog.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int wicht)
            {
                result.confirm();
            }
        }).setCancelable(false)
        .create()
        .show();
        return true;
    };
    });
```

Code source [here](http://lexandera.com/2009/01/adding-alert-support-to-a-webview/)

gl

Comment: Don't know why, but this method is ignored in my app.

Comment: The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68794366/1454514) actually works great.

Answer (score 3):

There are **3** types of js alerts:

- ***alert box*** - with an *Ok* button to proceed.
- ***confirm box*** - with both *OK* and *cancel* button.
- ***prompt box*** - get a value from the user and then select *OK/Cancel.*

---

- Use **onJsAlert** for **alertBox** .
- Use **onJsConfirm** for **confirmBox** .
- Use **onJsPrompt** for **promptBox**

> I have added the sample code for onJsConfirm,

```
        webViewLayout.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean onJsConfirm(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {

            AlertDialog dialog =new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext()).
                    setTitle("Confirm").
                    setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(view.getContext(),R.drawable.image)).
                    setMessage(message).
                    setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            result.cancel();
                        }
                    }).
                    setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            FlashMessage("JS");
                            result.confirm();
                        }
                    })
                    .create();
            dialog.show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible, i did that

```
   webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {




        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, final android.webkit.JsResult result)
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
            .setTitle("Calendário App...")
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                    new AlertDialog.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int wicht)
                {
                    result.confirm();
                }
            }).setCancelable(false)
            .create()
            .show();
            return true;
        };
            });
```

Comment: Don't know why, but this method is also ignored in my app.

Comment: @LuisA.Florit In my opinion, maybe it was onJsComfirm get called instead of onJsAlert.